# Did I damage my scanner?

Tags: antenna

I mounted a magnet mount scanner antenna next to my 25 watt ham magnet mount antenna. My scanner doesn't seen as sensitive as it used to be.

Could I have damaged the scanner by transmitting with the ham radio while scanner was turned on?

Comment: You mean you were transmitting on your 25W ham near your scanner antenna.  Oh oh.

Answer (score 3):

In short: maybe. It depends how close the antennas were, how well they couple, and exactly what the receive preamp on the scanner looks like, but it's definitely *very possible* that you put enough power into it to blow something up. If you're noticing symptoms... well, you're probably right.

Answer (score 3):

If pin diodes are used for front-end protection on the Scanner, the duration of Tx power injected will increase front end losses.

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-58710-3

Comment: Or the wide-band front end right at the ANT.

Comment: Any front end would need diode clamps which will heatup and becomes lossy with progressive damage.   A FET would otherwise fail in a catastrophic mode.